# How to Implement Authentication Guard without Authentication Defaults

Tags: php, laravel

**Authentication Defaults**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

**Authentication Guards**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],        
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students',
    ]

],
```

**User Providers**

```
 'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,      
    ],

    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Student::class,
    ]

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

when i try to login using **student** table `username`, `password` its not login but when i change the
**Auth Defaults** to students

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'students',
],
```

and api to students provider

```
'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
```

its login using students table data but the **users** table datas not allow to login.

> How can i implement this two users table to login??

*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

you should pass guard name to auth function :

```
auth('students')->login();
```

or

```
Auth::guard('students')->login()
```

or you override default guard by passing there to auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:students'] ], function(){
       //your routes here
    });
```